# Why I can not find some css with grep?

Tags: 7

I'm newbie and I don't know how Drupal 7 work!
I want to remove with and height from below code:

```
<img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://ashkanplastic.loc/sites/default/files/styles/large/public/slider-1a_0.jpg?itok=k4X3QU5U" width="480" height="236" alt="">
```

Could you please introduce to me why I can not find 480 with `$ grep -H -R 492`?
And please help to remove width and height.

Comment: I'm curious, why would you expect "492" would find you "480"?

Answer (score 1):

Please check [Remove width and height from img tag in Drupal output (for certain content type)](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/98240/remove-width-and-height-from-img-tag-in-drupal-output-for-certain-content-type) for removing width and height from image.

You will never find width and height with grep command because width and height are added by drupal theme function.

Check https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21image%21image.module/function/theme_image_style/7 and  https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/theme_image/7 for more details.